# Hover effect not showing in child div

Tags: html, css, hover

I have four categories in my solutions page, Oil&gas, utilities, Inteligent building, 
Industrial Engineering.

I have put a hover effect on each category there is a main div
called `pic_categry`(while hover the background colour change). And I have'
also put an hover effect in child div of `pic_categry` called `pic_catgry_img1`. My
problem is when I hovering the parent div(`pic_categry`) the hover effect of 
`pic_catgry_img1` is not working its working only hover that div. How can I display both hover effect when hovering parent div (`pic_categry`).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper4"> <a href="oil_n_gas.php">
            <div class="pic_categry">
              <div class="pic_catgry_img1"></div>
              <div class="pic_catgry_title">Oil N Gas</div>
            </div>
            </a>  <a href="smart_meter.php">
            <div class="pic_categry">
              <div class="pic_catgry_img3"></div>
              <div class="pic_catgry_title">Utilities</div>
            </div>
            </a>  <a href="inteligent.php">
            <div class="pic_categry">
              <div class="pic_catgry_img2"></div>
              <div class="pic_catgry_title">Intelligent Building</div>
            </div>
            </a>  <a href="industrial_engineering.php">
            <div class="pic_categry  align_tab">
              <div class="pic_catgry_img4"></div>
              <div class="pic_catgry_title">Industrial Engineering </div>
            </div>
            </a> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pic_categry {
    width: 233px;
    height: 239px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #425B97;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-right:23px;
}
.pic_categry:hover {
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    border-radius:4px;
    color:#263a87 !important;
}
.pic_catgry_title {
    font-family:'Varela', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.pic_catgry_title:hover {
    color:#263a87;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
.pic_catgry_img1 {
    width: 157px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_oil.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
.pic_catgry_img1:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_oil.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.pic_catgry_img2 {
    width: 157px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_smart.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
.pic_catgry_img2:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_smart.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.pic_catgry_img3 {
    width: 157px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image:url(../images/new/ind_utlts.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
.pic_catgry_img3:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_utlts.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.pic_catgry_img4 {
    width: 157px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image:url(../images/new/ind_heavy.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
.pic_catgry_img4:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_heavy.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Comment: post the html and css

Comment: sorry. I have updated

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Also having all that placed in `<a>` is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your code like this:

```
.pic_catgry_img1:hover{
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_oil.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

to

```
.pic_categry:hover .pic_catgry_img1{
    background-image: url(../images/new/ind_oil.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

so you can apply hover effects changes on child div while mouse enters parent div.

Comment: That right solution! But best experience: change only dependent properties (in this case, only background-position).

Comment: yeah. Its worked. Thank you so much for your time. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can apply my answer by the way =)

Answer (score 0):

change the background color and use your desired image

```
.pic_categry > .pic_catgry_img1:hover{background-color:#FF0000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.pic_categry:hover .pic_catgry_img1{
    background-position: left bottom;  //only need this
}
```

from @Atrem Fitiskin 's comment

> change only dependent properties (in this case, only
>   background-position).